# CodeIgniter - Present view depending upon screen size

Tags: codeigniter, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive site with the CodeIgniter framework and I have encountered a problem that I hope someone can help with.

The site itself is essentially a means to search through a large database of information and present the results nicely formatted in a table.

Because of the lack of screen real estate on a mobile phone the search terms and results will be reduced on these devices to only 3 out of the 20+ that will be available on a full desktop browser, meaning there will only be three fields in the database that will be searched on and presented back to the user on these smaller devices.

Anyway, I know how to style the pages responsively using media queries, but is there a way to actually build the content of the search forms depending upon the device's screen size?

For example I see it working a bit like so:

1. User navigates to search page
2. Page detects they're on a mobile phone
3. Page's search entry form is built with only 3 fields

or if they're on a desktop browser:

1. User navigates to search page
2. Page detects they're on a desktop browser
3. Page's search entry form is built with the full 20+ fields

I hope this makes some sense.
"What about tablets?" you might ask, well they'll be catered for too, but it's yet to be decided how many search fields they'll be presented with.

All ideas and advice is gratefully received.
Tony.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [User Agent class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html) to detect if people are using a mobile phone while visitting your site.

This has, ofcourse, a few drawbacks, but will allow you to recognize server side if a user is using a mobile device. Largest drawback I see: if the user is using a not known user agent, which actually is a mobile phone, you'll serve him 20 fields, instead of 3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @bram. I agree with you that the largest drawback is relying on the list of devices in the config/user_agents.php file. It always has the potential to be out of date. If it **is** the only server-side solution however I may have little choice... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 you don't need to do either user-agent or modernizer.

Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  table td:nth(4n) { display: none; }
}
```

Should be able to give you what you need.  You can also change it to @media mobile .... and see if it picks that up too, but given different devices have different screen widths I prefer to do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think detection can be done via java scripts / HTML / CSS (just i think... not sure about other options)

and, this can solve all the things.
No need to use CI.

```
http://modernizr.com/
```

More options are appreciable. :)